# How do I make the 'Pace.js' progress bar load faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am using the pace.js (http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)  progress bar that loads as my page renders. You will see the progress bar here when you run it:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/tkaf3r3k/

```
  for (u = {
  catchupTime: 100,
  initialRate: .03,
  minTime: 250,
  ghostTime: 100,
  maxProgressPerFrame: 20,
  easeFactor: 1.25,
  startOnPageLoad: !0,
  restartOnPushState: !0,
  restartOnRequestAfter: 500,
  target: "body",
  elements: {
    checkInterval: 100,
    selectors: ["body"]
  },
```

I have a good bit of CSS and JS files and I am trying to speed up the load time. I have reduced image size and put the scripts at the bottom of the page. I have also added some JS in the CSS link. I have minified the code as well. But my page needs to load faster. I want the progress bar to get to complete as fast as possible.

I don’t need everything to load for the page to be operational. I just want it to look like it fully loads when the progress bar is completely loaded. I just need to make sure the parts load that need to be loaded to make the page functional. Some of the scripts can load after. I am sure there is some JS that can exclude a group of files.

Any thoughts on how I can speed up the load time for the progress bar?

Comment: may I ask how is this related to pace.js? it seems like you want your scripts to be loaded faster and *if you achieve that* the progress bar will get to a complete state faster

Comment: absolutely, that is one direction, having the scripts load faster would solve it. But I am open to manipulating the code in pace.js with an exclude JS command so some files are left out of the progress bar loading. Or changing how or where it is pulling information from the page. I am a JS novice. The progress bar is a request by my customer, and I just need to make sure that it is fast loading...and I am open to any way to get to that. The page LOOKS like it loads much faster when I remove the progress bar because everything is visually there. The progress bar is so slow loading all the files

Comment: First note that pace.js doesn't load anything, it only "intercepts" the calls the browser does to get your scripts among other things so everything is fully automated, it seems like you can configure it so that some of these checks are skipped by adding the following script **before** including the pace.js script `<script>paceOptions = {
  ajax: false,
  document: false,
  eventLag: false
}</script>`, that way perhaps you don't need to modify the source code of the library